# SQL Server: unique key violation with select distinct

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, unique, distinct

I have following strange problem:

I need to fill some table with pseudorandom data. In this case I have 10 unique columns. Please don't discuss this scenario, it is test only.

I get some tables - one table for each unique column. From each of this tables I select distinct top XX values I need to insert to the final table. Due to the randomness request I perform ordering by ROWID() and joining all "column-tables" into one select which is inserted into given table.

Example:

```
 CREATE TABLE  uqtest (col1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
                       col2 INT UNIQUE, 
                       col3 INT UNIQUE, 
                       col4 INT UNIQUE,...

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[uqtest] WITH (TABLOCK)([col1],[col2],[col3],...

 SELECT [col1].[col1],[col2].[col2],[col3].[col3],...
 FROM 
 (                
  SELECT col1,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RID
           FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 col1 FROM [TEMPGEN_UNIQUE_uqtest_col1] ) AS col1
        ) AS col1
  INNER JOIN 
   (
            SELECT col2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RID
            FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 col2 FROM [TEMPGEN_UNIQUE_uqtest_col2] ) AS col2
        ) AS col2
 ON col1.RID = col2.RID
INNER JOIN (
                 SELECT col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS RID
            FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 col3 FROM [TEMPGEN_UNIQUE_uqtest_col3] ) AS col3
        ) AS col3
 ON col2.RID = col3.RID
```

....

And so on. (This scripts are generated)

I get following error message:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_*uqtest*_9017EE603E52440B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.uqtest'.

In my case it is `col10`.

When I tried select `col10` and `select distinct col10` results was equal.

Another test:

I created temp table

```
   CREATE TABLE test10 (col VARCHAR(255))
```

inserted data into this table and then built unique index on it's single column - everything was OK.

And my last guess:

I created the table including the uq constraint

```
 CREATE TABLE test10 (col VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE)
```

and inserted data (using the same select, however, with one column only) and it finished sucesfully.

I'm sure I'm the only user connected to the server. The table is empty before inserting.

Lot of thanks for any hint!

Comment: The table `uqtest` has integer columns but in your test you have `varchar(255)`. Is there a reason for that? Values that are different represented as `varchar` might end up as duplicates when implicitly converted to integer.

Comment: No..the table has 10 columns - some are INT and some VARCHAR. Here I declared only first 3... But the error get I on the varchar one. When I tried to delete this contraint, I get the same error on another column...

Comment: I would guess that you have a copy and paste error somewhere in the code that you've *not* shown (my guess is in an `ON` clause) such that one of the `INNER JOIN`s is actually degenerating into a cartesian join. E.g. if after the `col5` subquery, you forgot to change the `ON` condition and had it still saying `col3.rid = col4.rid`, it would not constraint the matching rows on `col5`.

Comment: No...really not. However, I have some guess - it comes from the NEWID() sorting order. Now I'm not absolutely sure why, but without this clause everything went OK.